# is there way to make faster to write to a file?

Tags: python, file, pandas

```
with open(filepath) as fp:
   #line = fp.readline()
   cnt = 1
   while line:
       line = fp.readline()
       print("Line {}%: {}".format(cnt, line.strip()))

       line = line.replace('\n', '')
       #print('line->',line)
       rst = read_ct[read_ct['user_id']==line]
       #print(rst)
       if rst.shape[0] != 0:
           AI = rst.iloc[0,1]
       else:
           AI ='32'
       index=df2[df2['id']==AI].index[0]

       df['distances'] = cosine_similarity(df, df.iloc[0:index])
       n = 1000 # or however many you want
       n_largest = df['distances'].nlargest(n + 1) # this contains the parent itself as the most similar entry, hence n+1 to get n children

       file.write(line)
       #file.writelines([df2.at[i,'article_id'] for i in list(n_largest.index)])

       for i in list(n_largest.index):
            file.write(" "+df2.at[i,'article_id'])




       file.write('\n') 
       #break
       cnt += 1
```

I'm trying to write some preprocessed data to the file
but it takes too long so want to gather the idea to make it faster

its writing 1000 results for each ID 
want to know how to make this code "faster"

Comment: Use the python [profiler](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/profile.html) to see where your script is spending the most time.

Comment: This code is doing a whole lot more than just writing to a file! Please explain what you are calculating. See [ask].